# JsUnit ant build not finding jsunit/acceptor

Tags: javascript, ant, jsunit

I'm trying to create a distributed test using [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit). When I run my ant build (after having set the properties as I think they should be), the testrunner runs my test on my local machine. The tests are green, but it is unable to submit the results to jsunit/acceptor. I'm getting a 405 HTTP error.

I have jsunit 2.2 installed, and there are no files called "acceptor" or anything like it in the root folder, or anywhere else for that matter. I tried downloading 2.1, which does have a Java class called `ResultAcceptorServlet.java`, but it's not finding that class (I'm not even sure that it *should* be finding that class) and is causing a 404 error.

Any help or pointers would be helpful. I've done searches on Google, but there seems to be a real lack of documentation and help online.